# How to stop buzzer once door sensor is opened

Tags: arduino

Basically the main objective of this question is knowing how to stop the buzzer action once the door sensor is opened (LOW). (Detecting the first opening of the door sensor after the alarm start buzzing)

But with the code that I wrote, when the buzzer rings and I open the door sensor, it will stop but once I put it back, it will keep ringing.

```cpp
void alarm1() //E.g. This is the first alarm
{
  state = digitalRead(sensor);

  if( Hor == 18 && (Min == 13 || Min == 14) && state == LOW) //Comparing the current time with the Alarm time
  {   
    Buzzer();

    lcd.clear();

    lcd.print("1st Alarm ON");

    lcd.setCursor(0,1);

    lcd.print("Morning Medicine");

  }
  else
  {         //Once user open the door sensor, the alarm will stop buzzing
    noTone(buz);
  }
  delay(200);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It becomes pretty easy once you have more than one alarm time. Then you can just create a queue and wait for the next alarm.

As long as you have only one alarm you have to make sure you only trigger it once per 24 hours. For example by checking the time down to milliseconds so there is no chance to close the door within the alarm time.

There are many ways. Just think about it. Once you decided what to do, try to implement it and if you fail come back here and present your failed attempt